# How to use Checked HTML Attribute in Svelte Checkbox?

Tags: laravel, svelte

I'm making a simple CRUD in Laravel and Svelte. I have one checkbox field and I would like to give "checked" attribute so it's checked by default. The problem is that Svelte throws error if I try to do so saying "Attribute needs to be unique":

```
<input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="remember" bind:checked={$form.remember} checked>
```

How do I use checked HTML attribute in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that is the desired default, I would just initialize the `form` store accordingly.

An alternative might be using an action, e.g.

```js
function check(node) { node.setAttribute('checked', '') }
```

```
<input ... use:check />
```

Would not recommend that, it fights the existing binding.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't realize all I need to do was just changing the remember from false to true in the form.

Comment: Great! If this answered the question, you can accept it using the checkmark outline on the side.